# Search ignores if searched with some words

Tags: solr

I am using sitecore with Solr. If I have the item name e.g. "Use a summer grill". When SOlr query search as _name:"Use a summer grill" it doesn't find.

But if I use "Use a summer" it will find. If I rename and place the word grill somewhere other than at the end e.g. "Grill is used in summer", it searches and finds.

I used the stopwords.txt, synonyms.txt, it's not there. What would be the possible cause?

Comment: What does debugQuery=true show for both queries? What does the analysis page under admin show for the content you've indexed for the query? When you're searching with quotes, you're usually performing a phrase search, which means that you expect the terms to be in sequence of each other (i.e. that "grill" comes after "summer").

Comment: I used the analysis on admin tool: after adding that word I can see a phrase coming as "grill Driver " in synonyms. However that's commented on synonyms.txt on all cores of that index on all three zookeeper cloud servers. Where else shall I check

Comment: Removed tags from title; noise reduction.